# Delete an ALAsset

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm using a photo viewer and i wan't to implement a trash button.

I already have the button ready and everything is good to go but the following:

How do I actually delete the ALAsset??

I tried searching in many places but couldn't find an answer...

Thanks,

For some reason i'm not allowed to post this question so i'm adding an irrelevant code of my trash button:

```
UIBarButtonItem *trash = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemTrash target:self action:@selector(trashButtonHit:)];
```

Comment: Can you please post your code for how you created photo viewer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't delete an `ALAsset`, there is no API for this.

An `ALAsset` is link to a file in the Photo library, which is outside of the sandbox of your app. The assets library allows you the acces the file in the photo library but they are read only.

Answer (score 2):

ALAssets are not read only:

```
editable
   Indicates whether the asset is editable. (read-only)

   @property(nonatomic, readonly, getter=isEditable) BOOL editable
```

And the documentation goes on to describe how to edit an ALAsset (your app must have created it). But the documentation offers no 'delete'. This is kind of silly, as your app could edit the photo down to a 1x1 px image, or a 'skull and crossbones', etc.

I think what happens is that Apple saves the original, so you can't delete the image, only edit it.

I can see what Apple is driving at - they don't want Applications to delete photos and 'surpise' the user. But some applications might want to have their own editing facilities, including a trash can.

The answer, then is to recreate the entire camera roll interface in your own app, and store images in your own storage.

Comment: The phrase using `Own Storage` is some what saddening. But, on the brighter side, i guess we can delete this Little devil by changing the it's MetaData.